# Form with two classes and relation

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2

i have in Doctrine 1.2:

```
User:
  columns:
    login:        { type: string(255), notnull: true }
    password:     { type: string(255), notnull: true }

Student:
  columns:
    user_id:         { type: integer, notnull: true }
    school_name:     { type: string(255) }
    school_year:     { type: integer(4) }
  relations:
    User:  { onDelete: CASCADE, local: user_id, foreign: id }

Teacher:
  columns:
    user_id:   { type: integer, notnull: true }
    city:      { type: string(255) }
    street:    { type: string(255) }
  relations:
    User:  { onDelete: CASCADE, local: user_id, foreign: id }
```

if i open **localhost/user/new** have in form:

```
login:
password:
```

this is good.

if i open **localhost/student/new** have in form:

```
user_id
school_name:
school_year:
```

but i would like:

```
login:
password:
school_name:
school_year:
```

how to do this? thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a sfForm method called **embedRelation**. You have to create a new form extending *userForm* and set (in the configure method) the embed relation with Student.

For example:

```
class UserStudentForm extends UserForm
{
  public function configure()
  {
    // Existing Student forms
    $this->embedRelation('Student');

    $this->widgetSchema->setNameFormat('user_student[%s]');
  }
}
```

Check [this example](http://prendreuncafe.com/blog/post/2009/11/29/Embedding-Relations-in-Forms-with-Symfony-1.3-and-Doctrine) that explains perfectly how to use it.